# How to use parted in script mode?

Tags: shell-script, parted

I'm trying to troubleshoot a script that used to work in some scenarios before. If I substitute script variables, what I'm trying to run is:

```
parted -s /dev/sdb unit MiB resizepart 1 307199
```

This produces:

```
Warning: Partition /dev/sdb1 is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?
```

But after this there is the OS prompt with no changes to feed an answer to parted. More over, if I run it without `-s`:

```
parted /dev/sdb unit MiB resizepart 1 307199
```

I'm getting this:

```
Warning: Partition /dev/sdb1 is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?
Yes/No? Yes
End?  [102399MiB]?
```

I'm not sure why am I being asked about End, if it was already provided on the command line above, can you explain?

Here is some more diagnostic commands:

```
# parted -v
parted (GNU parted) 3.3
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by <http://git.debian.org/?p=parted/parted.git;a=blob_plain;f=AUTHORS>.

# parted /dev/sdb unit MiB print
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 307200MiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start    End        Size       File system  Name     Flags
 1      1.00MiB  102399MiB  102398MiB  ext4         primary
```

The end goal is to be able to continue using this in a script, that is without human input at the runtime.

Comment: You might have the same problem reported here: [GNU parted resizepart in script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/190317)